# Trouble with MAUI app on iPad Mini 4 (v15.8)

Tags: iphone, ipad, maui

I have a maui app that runs fine on an iPhone but shows the splash screen for about 30 seconds then terminates on an iPad Mini 4 (v15.8). I tried the tabbed view sample and get the same result. I don't have much experience on iPads so not really sure where to look for more detailed diagnostic info. The last couple of lines from VS output tab are:

Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E51C3BF9-D02F-4A92-AF86-DF119355376C/ShopZone.app/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E51C3BF9-D02F-4A92-AF86-DF119355376C/ShopZone.app/System.Net.Sockets.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E51C3BF9-D02F-4A92-AF86-DF119355376C/ShopZone.app/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E51C3BF9-D02F-4A92-AF86-DF119355376C/ShopZone.app/System.Private.Uri.dll [External]
The app has been terminated.

Thanks for any ideas/pointers.

Comment: Following...I have the same issue but with an iPad Mini 5th Generation. Works great on an iPad 10th Generation. (17.3.1)